# htaccess preventing "<script>" in url and hex script

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url

I am working with htaccess and I want to secure my website from attacks/injections of scripts in the url and I want to deny access to my site and record their ip address and deny them if they run their script it will stop it and close their browser .is it possible because from experience I have been using htaccess to hide the extension name of the pages that I have made help with this one would really be great.

and also this code which redirects

```
Redirect 301 / http://www.newdomain.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, there's a way to use a `.htaccess` file to detect whether `<script>` is in the URL and redirect them if so, but hopefully that's not your only line of defense. If you start blocking `<script>`, then maybe they'll start using `<script >` or `<img onload="">` or, or, or… [oh dear](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet). The point is that filtering attacks is insufficient; instead, let them submit whatever data they want (even if it appears malicious), but prevent it from doing any harm by escaping appropriately.

That said, a `RewriteRule` like this might do it:

```
RewriteRule <script> http://www.example.com/ [L,R]
```

To log it, you could have not `.htaccess` do the redirect but rather route the request to some server-side script which logged it and then redirected. Alternatively you could just filter the access log yourself.